# Mock Smart Contract For Unit Testing

Tags: solidity, truffle, contract-design, storage, unittesting

I'm new to Ethereum and solidity, I'm developing a simple decentralized application using Truffle where I have an abstract contract `Storage` and another contract `Reader` which uses storage.

```
contract Storage {
    function getWeight() public view returns(uint8);
    function setWeight(uint8 weight) public view returns(bool); 
}

contract Reader {
    Storage private storage;
    constructor(address storageAddress) {
        storage = Storage(storageAddress);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to write unit test for contract `Reader`, is there anyway to mock the behavior of the abstract contract? If not, then what is the best practices for that situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a little implementation of the Storage contract. Note that I renamed your abstraction to StorageInterface.

I also added some functions to Reader, since there isn't much to test unless it does something. So, now you have a setter/getter in the Reader that forwards to a Storage contract which is an implementation of the interface.

On looking at it, I decided I was uncomfortable with using "Storage" because this is a reserved word in the lower case form. I also dispensed with the `uint8` that looks like premature optimization.

One other little thing. The Interface declared the setter as `view`, but it can't be since it writes to the contract state.

```
pragma solidity 0.4.24;

contract StoreInterface {
    function getWeight() public view returns(uint);
    function setWeight(uint weight) public returns(bool); 
}

/**
 * Just a very simple set of stubs ...
 * Deploy a "Store" and then pass its address into Reader's constructor.
 */

contract Store is StoreInterface {

    uint weight;

    event LogSetWeight(address sender, uint weight);

    function getWeight() public view returns(uint) {
        return weight;
    }

    function setWeight(uint _weight) public returns(bool) {
        weight = _weight;
        emit LogSetWeight(msg.sender, _weight);
        return true;
    } 
}

contract Reader {

    StoreInterface store;

    constructor(address storeAddress) public {
        store = StoreInterface(storeAddress);
    }

    function getWeight() public view returns(uint) {
        return store.getWeight();
    }

    function setWeight(uint weight) public returns(bool) {
        return store.setWeight(weight);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

The other approach would be to use a mocking library, like [Doppelganger](https://github.com/EthWorks/Doppelganger)